# Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. WebRunLoopLock

Tags: ios, nsrunloop

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x9a42a90: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   0x5978c88 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
2   0x2e59afe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
3   0x2e59a3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers
4   0x2e37704 __CFRunLoopRun
5   0x2e36f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   0x2e36e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   0x5978c50 RunWebThread(void*)
8   0x9c81eed9 _pthread_start
9   0x9c8226de thread_start
```

above log come when a textfield begin editing.

Comment: MAny times this means you are doing some UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: You did [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com), right?

Comment: this crash is due to your code is running in background thread so load your code in main thread.